# Wrap Hint in PhoneTextBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

is it possible to make the Hint text in the `PhoneTextBox` of the Windows Phone Toolkit wrap? I have looked into the code and it seems that this is only possible by changing the whole `ControlTemplate`. Have I missed something? Is there an easier solution?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Unless there is a dependency property for that, control template is your only option. What stops you from doing just that?

Comment: That duplicates code, so I usually try to avoid it. But if there is no other option, it is obviously the way to go.

Comment: Why do you need a hint so long?

Comment: I have a long text box. And I need to display some detailed instructions without wasting too much space, so I thought that would be a good idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I can replace the `ContentControl` via the hint style without re-styling the whole control like this:

```
<Style x:Key="HintContentControlStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then apply it to the `PhoneTextBox`:

```
<tk:PhoneTextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HintStyle="{StaticResource HintContentControlStyle}" Hint="{Binding LocalizedResources.Hint, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```